# Viewport is not working for using page width of 1170px for mobile devices, how to fix?

Tags: mobile, viewport, device

I used below things but not working, my page width is 1170px and its not fit it into the mobile devices. Am new in this site any one can help me out? thanks in advance.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> 
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<meta name="viewport" content=", initial-scale=0.5" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, user-scalable = yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 0.33, user-scalable = yes"></meta>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 980px, initial-scale=0.4, maximum-scale=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the below.

Under the Head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

Under your stylesheet:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Your Styles */
```

Put all your tags, ID's, Classes, selectors, etc in the above @media and you will get your stuff proper for multiple device platforms.

Hope this helps.